# Tensorflow-datasets: Cannot batch tensors of different shapes error even after resize?

Tags: python, tensorflow, computer-vision

Having some trouble with the `tensorflow-datasets` module. Using the `stanford_dogs` dataset, I resize images to `[180,180]`, yet when the model is trained, from the error message, it appears `tensorflow` is trying to load the images in their original sizes.

What am I doing wrong?

Code to replicate error (and the error) below. Dataset is around `750mb`. Can copy paste it into `google colab` and run to replicate.

```
import io
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds

def _normalize_img(img, label):
    img = tf.cast(img, tf.float32) / 255.
    img = tf.image.resize(img,[180,180])
    return (img, label)
    

train_dataset, test_dataset = tfds.load(name="stanford_dogs", split=['train', 'test'], as_supervised=True)

train_dataset = train_dataset.shuffle(1024).batch(32)
train_dataset = train_dataset.map(_normalize_img)

test_dataset = test_dataset.batch(32)
test_dataset = test_dataset.map(_normalize_img)

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64,2,padding='same',activation='relu',input_shape=(180,180,3)),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32,2,padding='same',activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(120,activation='softmax')
])


model.compile(
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.001),
    loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy')


history = model.fit(
    train_dataset,
    epochs=5)
```

Fails with the error:

```
InvalidArgumentError:  Cannot batch tensors with different shapes in component 0. First element had shape [278,300,3] and element 1 had shape [375,500,3].
     [[node IteratorGetNext (defined at <ipython-input-29-15023f95f627>:39) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_4908]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You encounter this error because the `tf.data.Dataset` API cannot create a batch of tensors with different shapes. As the batch function will return Tensors of shape `(batch, height, width, channels)`, the `height`, `width` and `channels` values must be constant throughout the dataset. You can read more about why in the [Introduction to Tensors guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/tensor).

Batching after resizing will solve your issue :

```py
train_dataset = train_dataset.shuffle(1024)
train_dataset = train_dataset.map(_normalize_img)
# we batch once every image is the same size
train_dataset = train_dataset.batch(32)
```